# Как сделать в ajax Обработку на insert и update....в бд

Tags: insert, ajax, php, update, javascript

И как правильней разделить события в обработчике?
вот код:

```
<?session_start(); error_reporting(0);?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Простой пример использования AJAX</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SendRequest(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "obrabotchik.php",
        data: "sid=<?=session_id()?>&data_1="+$('#data_1').val()+"&data_2="+$('#data_2').val()+"&db="+$('#db').val(),
        success: function(response1){
            $('#response1').html(response);
        }
    });
};
function UpdateRequest(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "obrabotchik.php",
        data: "sid=<?=session_id()?>&before="+$('#before').val()+"&after="+$('#after').val(),
        success: function(response){
            $('#response2').html(response2);
        }
    });
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Запрос</th>
            <th>Ответ сервера</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Переменная 1: <input type="text" size="10" id="data_1" /></label><br />
                <label>Переменная 2: <input type="text" size="10" id="data_2" /></label><br />
                <label><input type="text" id="db"></label>
                <button onclick="SendRequest();">Послать запрос</button>
            </td>
            <td><div id="response1"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <label>Что заменить? :<input type="text" size="10" id="before" /></label><br />
        <label>На что Заменить: <input type="text" size="10" id="after" /></label><br />
        <button onclick="UpdateRequest();">Обновить</button>
        </td>
        <td><div id="response2">

        </div></td>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

код обработчика:

```
<?
session_start();
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pswd = '';
$db = 'my_bd';

$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pswd);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connection);
if(!$connection || !mysql_select_db($db,$connection))
{
    exit(mysql_error());
}
if(session_id() != $_POST['sid']) die('Wrong Request');
if(isset($_POST['db']) && (!empty($_POST['db'])) ){
    echo $_POST['db'];
    $s=$_POST['db'];
     $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytabl(source) VALUES ('$s')");
    echo "Статья успешно добавлена!";
}
$before=$_POST['before'];
$after=$_POST['after'];
if(!empty($before) && !empty($after)){
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE mytabl SET source='$after' WHERE source=$before ");

}
?>
Значение переменной 1:<br />
<strong><?=$_POST['data_1']?></strong>
<hr />
Значение переменной 2:<br />
<strong><?=$_POST['data_2']?></strong>
<strong><?=$_POST['db']?></strong>
```

Comment: @Анатолийй

    sid=<?=session_id()?>

Это беда и совсем уж открытое предоставление доступа зловредам от имени честного пользователя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как жестко накодено =(

При таком раскладе, ваш проект долго не проживет, в случае если кто то узнает в какой классный файл нужно посылать запросы =)

Проще все переписать и сделать более грамотно:

Создать форму на странице (не принципиально, но лучше будет)

Написать post запрос и передать в обработчик все данные с формы (serialize())

Данный обработчик на PHP снести совсем и писать новый, более качественный с проверкой всех принятых данных!

Могу написать ток пример без обработчика (в PHP уж как нибудь сами разберитесь, но нынешний лучше удалите)

К примеру на странице есть простая HTML форма

```
    <form name="form">
    <input name="field" type="text" value="первый инпут">
    <input name="field2" type="text" value="второй инпут">
    <input name="field3" type="checkbox" value="чекбокс"> Выбрать
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
            <div id="error"></div>
</form>
```

Пишем скрипт

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('[name="form"]').submit(function(){
            $('#error').html('');
            var form = $('[name="form"]').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/obrabotchik.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: form,
                complete: function() {},
                statusCode: {
                    200: function() {
                        // в случае успеха (статус заголовка 200) выводим сообщение
                    },
                    403: function(jqXHR) {
                        // 403, какая то ошибка, выводим сообщение в div#error
                        var error = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                        $('#error').html(error.message);
                    }
                }
            });
            return;
        });
    });
</script>
```

И уже обработчик на PHP /obrabotchik.php

Принимаем данные в объект и не по детски обрабатываем все данные, поле за полем (ну тут уже сами как то, очень много писать)

получится объект в виде

```
{
    field: 'первый инпут',
    field2: 'второй инпут',
    field3: 'чекбокс'
}
```